# Tracking marker clicks on Google Maps - Using google tag manager

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-analytics, google-maps-markers, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to track people clicking on map markers with google Tag Manager, is this possible and if so, what are my options?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would expect so, see https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#events

You want to trigger this `dataLayer.push` event on click of the markers, e.g.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    dataLayer.push({'event': 'markerClick'});
}
```

Comment: This gets the event pushed to the dataLayer, but don't forget you'll also need rules and GA Event tags in GTM to get the event into Google Analytis.

Comment: in what way doesn't it work?  You might want to add your code to your question

Comment: Also include your firing rules and GA Tag configuration.